# Loss of information during a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, set

I have a problem with this method:

```
private boolean reflectionEqualsSet(Object left, Object right) {

Set leftSet = (Set) left;
Set rightSet = (Set) right;

if (leftSet == null) {
    // POF tricks: if set to serialize is null, the deserialized set is empty
    return rightSet != null && rightSet.size() == 0;
}

// check size
if (leftSet.size() != leftSet.size()) {
    return false;
}

// check values
for (Object currLeft : leftSet) {
    boolean found = false;

    for (Object currRight : rightSet) {
        if (isEqual(currLeft, currRight)) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
}
```

The problem is:

I have an object with three random filled values in `leftSet` (2 UUID's and 1 Integer).
The values I have in my `leftSet` change completely in the for loop. While debugging I've found out that in the first iteration `currSet` already has completely different values and I can't figure out why.
In the inner loop with `currRight` this doesn't happen.

I've been debugging for hours and I've found the problem is in that line does anyone have an idea of why the values change? (Not the order, the values).
I know this isn't much information about the problem but that's all I can tell, I don't know how to explain it any better, sorry.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a short but complete example demonstrating the problem? What do you mean by `currSet`? (It's not in your code - did you mean `leftSet`?) What type of set are you using? What does `isEqual` do?

Comment: `currSet` is just an Object. `isEqual` compares if two objects are equal (not the point here). I'm using a normal `Set<>`
What happens sometimes is: the values I have in the objects within `leftSet` (UUID, Integer, UUID) are assigned to `currSet` and the values are something like: UUID+1, Random Integer, Random UUID

Comment: `Set` is an interface. Do you mean a `HashSet`? `LinkedHashSet`? Something else? Again, it would be *much* easier to help you if we could reproduce the issue...

Comment: What is the purpose of `leftSet.size() != leftSet.size()` check?

Comment: Voting to close this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your size check is off

```
// check size
// if (leftSet.size() != leftSet.size()) {
if (leftSet.size() != rightSet.size()) {
  return false;
}
```

Next, I don't trust your `isEqual` method - please `Override` [`Object.equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29),

```
// if (isEqual(currLeft, currRight)) {
if (currLeft.equals(currRight)) {
  return true; // <-- and just short-circuit with return true!
}
```

Obviously `return false;` after your `for` loop, and you can eliminate `found`.

Comment: I like: `"I don't trust your isEqual method..."`. It's the only hidden code up there that could possibly have side effects.

Comment: The information loss is before the `isEqual` method. I've done the changes you've sugested. The problem is in the for loop, as I've said.

Comment: @EduardoRocha: as Jon Skeet has already says, and as I concur, without your posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would allow us to reproduce your error, you can say anything you want, but you're not going to get a satisfactory answer.